# Django wiki (from its official website)

Tags: django

Choosing a wiki engine.

Django has a wiki at its official site. https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki I suppose this wiki engine must me rather stable and well supported. Maybe this is the best choice.

Could you tell me what is the name of this wiki application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`djangoproject.com` uses [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/) as an issue tracking system, Trac has a [built-in wiki engine](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracWiki) so I guess it is what they use (I grepped the djangoproject.com [source code](https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com) and did not find reference to any other Wiki engine).

A dedicated Wiki engine probably is a better choice than Trac's one but I have no expertise on the issue so I can't help you any further.

Comment: I'm a bit afraid of Wiki engines. They seem to be unstable. If they use Trac, there must be some reason for it.

Comment: Indeed but they do not use Trac for its Wiki engine